# UIImagePickerController source type photo library crash in Ipad iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, exc-bad-access

I try to present a UIImagePickerController from rect using this code:

```
UIImagePickerController* imgPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPickerController.delegate = self;
imgPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imgPickerController.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
imgPickerController.allowsEditing = NO;

_popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imgPickerController];

[_popover setDelegate:self];

[_popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(195, 55, 70, 64) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:NO];
```

But sometimes crash happends... NO always, sometimes run, sometimes crash...
This is the crash LOG:

```
Thread 0: Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreText                       0x2e4c0d1e TComponentFont::GetRawBoundingBox() const + 13
1  CoreText                       0x2e4b3ba7 TBaseFont::CalculateFontMetrics(bool) const + 110
2  CoreText                       0x2e4b3ba7 TBaseFont::CalculateFontMetrics(bool) const + 110
3  CoreText                       0x2e4c0d0b TComponentFont::CalculateFontMetrics(bool) const + 34
4  CoreText                       0x2e4b39fd TBaseFont::InitFontMetrics() const + 44
5  CoreText                       0x2e4b3839 TBaseFont::GetStrikeMetrics(float, CGAffineTransform const*, bool) const + 104
6  CoreText                       0x2e4b3603 TFont::InitStrikeMetrics() const + 38
7  CoreText                       0x2e4b35b9 CTFontGetAscent + 92
8  GraphicsServices               0x32a17245 GSFontEnsureExtraData + 228
9  GraphicsServices               0x32a19361 GSFontGetLatin1LayoutInfo + 44
10 UIFoundation                   0x359a252d -[UIFont(UIFont_AttributedStringDrawing) _getLatin1GlyphMapping:andAdvanceMapping:] + 12
11 UIFoundation                   0x35978e61 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 3784
12 UIFoundation                   0x3597df7f -[NSAttributedString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:context:] + 898
13 UIKit                          0x3085dcab -[UILabel _updateScaledMetricsForRect:] + 594
14 UIKit                          0x306023d3 -[UILabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:] + 206
15 PhotosUI                       0x3466608b -[PUFlatWhiteInterfaceTheme configureAlbumListSubtitleLabel:]
16 PhotosUI                       0x345bc141 +[PUAlbumListCellContentView _updateLabelGlobalCachedSizes]
17 libobjc.A.dylib                0x38588231 _class_initialize + 572
18 libobjc.A.dylib                0x3858f7a7 lookUpImpOrForward + 130
19 libobjc.A.dylib                0x38587feb _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 34
20 libobjc.A.dylib                0x38587db9 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 24
21 PhotosUI                       0x345bb059 -[PUAlbumListTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]
22 UIKit                          0x3069aa5b -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 410
23 UIKit                          0x30642e7d -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1804
24 UIKit                          0x30642699 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 184
25 UIKit                          0x30568da3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 346
26 QuartzCore                     0x301efc6b -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 142
27 QuartzCore                     0x301eb47b CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 350
28 UIKit                          0x3057dc1b -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 530
29 PhotosUI                       0x3467ec55 -[PUAbstractAlbumListViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]
30 UIKit                          0x30568e79 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 560
31 QuartzCore                     0x301efc6b -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 142
32 QuartzCore                     0x301eb47b CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 350
33 QuartzCore                     0x301eb30d CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
34 QuartzCore                     0x301ead1f CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 230
35 QuartzCore                     0x301eab2f CA::Transaction::commit() + 314
36 UIKit                          0x305610c3 _afterCACommitHandler + 126
37 CoreFoundation                 0x2ddc11cd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
38 CoreFoundation                 0x2ddbeb71 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 284
39 CoreFoundation                 0x2ddbeeb3 __CFRunLoopRun + 730
40 CoreFoundation                 0x2dd29c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
41 CoreFoundation                 0x2dd29a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
42 GraphicsServices               0x32a1d283 GSEventRunModal + 138
43 UIKit                          0x305cd049 UIApplicationMain + 1136
44 Puzz!                          0x00032665 main (main.m:16)
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Finally, I decided use a AssetsLibrary framework to create a custom UIImagePickerController using this MyImagePicker sample:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/myimagepicker/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: looks to me to be font related issue.. coreText errors out. ios7 has quite a few bugs in CoreText

Comment: please try and see if it happens when you set a different device language and/or default font size

Comment: @Daij-Djan I have not change the default font size, I am trying with Spanish. Do I try to change the default font? I try change language but persist the crash... :(